# Execute rsync command from script without prompt for passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I use rsync to deploy code to a remote server and currently I have passphrase for the security key. 
How can I add the passphrase in the rsync command without a prompt to use it in a script?

I don't use rsync-daemon.

My command:

```
rsync -vaz -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/key.ppk" --chmod=ugo=rwX --omit-dir-times --no-perms . user@domain.com:/var/www/html
```

Comment: Use an ssh key.

Comment: I already use, updated OP

Comment: OK, then use an ssh key that doesn't have a passphrase.

Comment: It's mandatory.

Comment: I think your company needs a more sane IT security department, then, if they're going to let you embed a plaintext passphrase in a script...

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm looking for alternatives like Athonia answer but It needs a rsync daemon. I don't know if the rsync daemon is the better option

Comment: If the generating SSH key without passphrase is an option, then try entering blank password on ssh-keygen 3 times and it will let you create a key without passphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your security independent of the password of the private key, by instead restricting the usage of the key on the server side:

1. Create a separate key pair used only for rsync. Make that private key passwordless.
2. On the server, make sure that you have the script `rrsync` available. (It will usually be installed with the rsync package, probably in `/usr/share/doc/rsync-VERSION/support`.
3. Add the public part of the key to the target user's authorized_keys on the server. At the start of the line, add a load of restriction to enforce that the key can only be used from the correct server and only to rsync things to a specific directory, like this:

```
command="/path/to/rrsync /var/www/html/",no-pty,no-port-forwarding,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,from="IPADRESS" ssh-rsa AAA[...]
```

Now you have a key that can be used only for one thing - to rsync things from one single server to the directory /var/www/html. The restrictions on the serverside mean that even if someone else gets hold of the key, the destruction they can wreak is very limited, and certainly far less than if they get hold of the password to a key that allows full access.

Comment: Note that this is can be used in combination with other security measures (e.g. the `ssh-agent` technique @foo suggested). In fact, I'd say that whatever else you may do, you *should* be using a server-side key restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the ssh key on disk with a passphrase and, when the host boots, unlock the key into an ssh-agent.

Then, when running, rsync, ensure that the correct environment variables are set to allow the use of the agent.

On boot, manually:

```
ssh-agent >$HOME/.ssh/agent_env  # will start a new ssh agent and store the details
. $HOME/.ssh/agent_env           # will load the stored environment into this shell
ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/key.ppk       # will prompt for passphrase
```

Then when running rsync, use a small wrapper script to source the `agent_env` file as above:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -e $HOME/.ssh/agent_env ] 
then
    No ssh agent details
    exit 1
fi
. $HOME/.ssh/agent_env
rsync ...
```

To be sure, have a `@reboot` cron job for the root user to delete the `$HOME/.ssh/agent_env` file:

```
@reboot rm $HOME/.ssh/agent_env
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you have a public key installed on the remote server that requires password (i.e. RSA key created by ssh keygen process)?

If so, have you tried either of these two techniques?

1. Set the environment variable RSYNC_PASSWORD to the password (could be visible to other users).
2. specify it at Command line --password-file option.  This option is more secure as long as the password file is NOT world readable.

What does the output look like when you attempt this? I have a colleague who has scripted a lot of these in his career so I can ask him if I have an example of what you're seeing.

Let me know.

Comment: I tried the step2 but it's no good: `The --password-file option may only be used when accessing an rsync daemon.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1400) [sender=3.1.2]`